# Reducing white space above date in Letter Class

Tags: spacing, letters

How can I reduce the amount of whitespace at the top of the page in the `letter` class?  I've added some text to serve as a letterhead, and everything is lined up... but starts way too low!  Does anyone have suggestions for how to get my first line of text to line up with the top?

```
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\signature{Nathan S. Lachenmyer}
\longindentation=0pt
\let\raggedleft\raggedright
\vfill

\begin{letter}{
Senior Staff Recruiter \\
XYZ Corporation \\
Rt. 56 \\
Anytown, New Jersey 05867}

%This is my header
\centerline{\huge \bf \sc Nathan S. Lachenmyer}
\begin{center}
\line(1,0){450}
\end{center}

%letter begins here
\opening{Dear Person:}

Letter goes here

\closing{Sincerely Yours,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can not comment yet, otherwise this would be a comment: but it seems that you can simply remove `\vfill` to get rid of the extra white space.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest approach here, without mucking around with page dimension modifications, is to insert a vertical re-adjustment using `\vspace*{<len>}` where `<len>` is some negative value. For example, in the following MWE, I've used `\vspace*{-10\baselineskip}` to vertically "back up" 10 lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\signature{Nathan S. Lachenmyer}
\longindentation=0pt
\let\raggedleft\raggedright

\begin{letter}{%
Senior Staff Recruiter \\
XYZ Corporation \\
Rt. 56 \\
Anytown, New Jersey 05867}

\vspace*{-10\baselineskip}% Correct for vertical displacement

%This is my header
\centerline{\huge \bf \sc Nathan S. Lachenmyer} \par
%\begin{center}
%\line(1,0){450}
%\end{center}
\hrulefill

%letter begins here
\opening{Dear Person:}

Letter goes here

\closing{Sincerely Yours,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

I've added the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) to highlight the page/type block dimensions setup using the `letter` document class. If you wish to change these to occupy more of the page real estate, use the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Ps. Instead of using `\line` with some fixed measurement to draw a horizontal line, use `\hrulefill`, which will fill across the entire text block without causing overful `\hbox` warnings.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for!  I couldn't figure out to add 'negative' vertical space to the file, but this works perfectly :)

Comment: You would have to customize the spacing for each and every letter. If you keep `\vspace*{-10\baselineskip}`, but add a few lines of text to the letter, the header shoots off the top of the page.

Comment: @asymptoticdesign: You should use @ DanielE.Shub's suggestion for removing the centred look of the letter. My solution provides a quick fix that works in your case.

Answer (score 11):

Inserting a negative space is going to be problematic since the amount of space needed depends on the length of the letter. The `letter` class centers the text on the first page when the length of the letter is only 1 page long. See line 414 in letter.cls

`\def\@texttop{\ifnum\c@page=1\vskip \z@ plus.00006fil\relax\fi}`

You can get a top aligned letter by adding

```
\makeatletter
  \def\@texttop{}
\makeatother
```

to your MWE.

You should also consider if you want to add your "header" information into the actual header of `ps@firstpage` (you could do this with `fancyhdr`). Then you can have a vertically centered 1 page letter with your header at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy method. Just use the `\vspace{-xxpt}` to reduce the space in the beginning of the letter. This command should be inserted just before the text line that shows the big gap. For. Ex. I have a large gap in my letter between my contact info and date. SO, just after my contact info, I inserted the command `\vspace{-40pt}`. You may need to adjust text height (`\textheight{10 in}` if the letter is two long to fit in to one page. It worked like a charm :).